# how to retrieve actual column value.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

In my work I have a table

```
reservation_available(seat_id, seat_type, flight_id, available)
```

where flight_id is a foreign key and seat_type has two value(Economic, Business) consecutively.
To retrieve the seat_id and available I wrote:

```
 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT seat_id, seat_type, available FROM reservation_available WHERE seat_type = 'Economic' AND reservation_available.flight_id = '" + flight_id + "' ", connection))
                {

                    string s_ID = seat_id.ToString();
                    string e_avail = EconomicAvailable.ToString();
                    string st = seat_type;


                    SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        s_ID = myReader[0].ToString();
                        st = myReader[1].ToString();
                        e_avail = myReader[2].ToString();

                    }
                    int sId = Convert.ToInt32(s_ID);
                    int eAvail = Convert.ToInt32(e_avail);

                    myReader.Close();
                    set2(sId, eAvail, st);
                }
```

and similar code for the seat_type = 'Business'.

But retrieved data only shows the "seat_id" of seat_type = "Business".
But I want respective seat_id for selected seat_type.

Help needed

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do, and specify also your model/database details?

Comment: You can send seat type as parameter or write condition as 'seat_type = 'Economic' or seat_type = 'Business''

Comment: @lexeRoy, I want to show seat_id of seat_type = 'Economic' when I select Economic, and seat_id of seat_type = 'Business' when I select Business type. I used two button to select Economic and Business.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal, If I do that, what will be the change in the code in the following :
'while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        s_ID = myReader[0].ToString();
                        st = myReader[1].ToString();
                        e_avail = myReader[2].ToString();
                    }'

if I add b_avail inside the curl brace :
             b_avail = myReader[0].ToString();
It will try to read another column or row, but available values are in the same column. I just tried to separate the available values bu declaring variable. May be this should change.

Comment: SELECT seat_id, seat_type, available FROM reservation_available WHERE (seat_type = 'Business' or seat_type = 'Economic') AND reservation_available.flight_id = '" + flight_id + "'


OR


SELECT seat_id, seat_type, available FROM reservation_available WHERE seat_type = '"+varSeatType+"'  AND reservation_available.flight_id = '" + flight_id + "'

Comment: Thanx @AmitAgrawal Bhai.. :) For your second code in last comment. I have changed my code to it.. Thanks for your cordial support :) :)

Comment: If this is helpful the I will add as a answer. You will accept this

Comment: Please note that you should be using parameterized queries. Concatenation is a big source of sql injection attack weakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT seat_id, seat_type, available FROM reservation_available WHERE (seat_type = 'Business' or seat_type = 'Economic') AND reservation_available.flight_id = '" + flight_id + "'
```

OR Parameter Based

```
SELECT seat_id, seat_type, available FROM reservation_available WHERE seat_type = '"+varSeatType+"' AND reservation_available.flight_id = '" + flight_id + "'
```